# Query returns wrong results when grouping by username

Tags: mysql

I want to display number of results (number of logins) per day. Problem with my query is that it returns wrong values. I think that problem is with grouping. Does someone knows where's the problem?

Also `logaction` row can contain numbers from 1-4 so I want to count how many rows are in 1,2, 3 and in 4 per day.

Here is code that I am using:

```
SELECT  username, DATE( Vrijeme) AS Datum, COUNT( logaction ) AS total
FROM user_login_action
WHERE DATE( Datum ) >=  '2015-04-06'
AND DATE( Datum ) <=  '2015-04-12'
AND username !=  ''
GROUP BY DATE( Datum ) , username
```

Comment: Can you show sample data, expected output and the output you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A problem in your query is this:
You have `DATE(Vrijeme) AS Datum` after `SELECT` but you use `DATE(Datum)` in `WHERE` and `GROUP BY`.

Is this query return your wanted results:

```
SELECT
    username, 
    DATE(Vrijeme) AS Datum, 
    COUNT( logaction ) AS total
FROM
    user_login_action
WHERE 
    DATE(Vrijeme) >=  '2015-04-06'
  AND 
    DATE(Vrijeme) <=  '2015-04-12'
  AND 
    username !=  ''
GROUP BY 
    DATE(Vrijeme),
    username
```